# All SoapUI test are not executing from Maven build

Tags: maven, jenkins, soapui

I have created a soapui test cases for testing rest webservice. All the steps are executing fine from SoapUI. But when i integrate it with maven and do build, not all steps are executing.

I am using groovy script to assert response.
Also using property transfers

Maven plugin config is like below:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
   <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>4.6.1</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>QClearanceTest</id>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>test</goal> 
                  </goals>
                  <phase>test</phase>           
               </execution>
            </executions>                       
            <configuration>
               <projectFile>soapui/soapui-project.xml</projectFile>          
               <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
               <junitReport>true</junitReport>
               <printReport>true</printReport>
               <projectProperties>
                  <projectProperty>NameInsured=Company</projectProperty>
               </projectProperties>
      <settingsFile>soapui\soapui-settings.xml</settingsFile>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after upgrading the plugin and adding a dependency:

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>QClearanceTest</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>test</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <projectFile>soapui/soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
            <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
            <printReport>true</printReport>
            <projectProperties>
                <projectProperty>NameInsured=Company</projectProperty>
            </projectProperties>
            <settingsFile>soapui\soapui-settings.xml</settingsFile>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
                <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.7</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

**soapui-settings.xml**

```
<con:soapui-settings xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
   <con:setting id="HttpSettings@socket_timeout">200000</con:setting>
</con:soapui-settings>
```